# How to change laravel sanctum return "message": "Unauthenticated."

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

I have integrated sanctum for API authentication. I was facing a problem of redirection if the `token` is unauthenticated and solved it using this answer on [laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/sanctum-api-authentication-redirects-to-login-page?page=1&replyId=695124)

I could get a JSON response like:

```
{
"message": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

What I am trying to do is to handle this response to be something like:

```
{
"status_code": 401,
"success":false,
"message": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

Thanks in advance ^^

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you check the source code of `laravel/sanctum` at this [line](https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/blob/2.x/src/Http/Middleware/CheckAbilities.php#L23)

```
 if (! $request->user() || ! $request->user()->currentAccessToken()) {
    throw new AuthenticationException;
 }
```

they use the `AuthenticationException` so you could overwrite it by using [`Rendering Exceptions`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#rendering-exceptions) by adding the register method in your `App\Exceptions\Handler` like this

```php
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;

public function register()
{
  $this->renderable(function (AuthenticationException $e, $request) {
    if ($request->is('api/*')) {
        return response()->json([
          'status_code' => 401,
          'success' => false,
          'message' => 'Unauthenticated.'
        ], 401);
    }
   });
}
```

you cloud read more about [`Rendering Exceptions`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#rendering-exceptions) in the docs

Comment: Thank you very much. This works perfectly. Knowing the right place to make the change is key in laravel. :)

Comment: any one using this , don't forget to import the AuthenticationException class in order for it to work